# jupyterlab 500 error from dataproc cluster

Tags: jupyter-lab, google-cloud-dataproc

i have been trying to open jupyterlab from my dataproc cluster. i had been working on it last week and there seemed to be some issue with the kernel. so i signed out of jupyterlab and stopped the cluster. then i tried to open jupyterlab again from the link under web interfaces in cluster detail. however, since last wednesday, everytime i try this i get a 500 or 502 error. the error says "500. That's an error. That's all we know."

i'm not sure what to do here. i googled the issue and couldn't find anything that would help.

Comment: You can try ssh into the master node and restart the jupyter service.

Comment: thanks for your reply. sorry but i'm very new to using gcloud platforms and don't know how to try ssh into the master node. can you explain? thanks.

Comment: `gcloud compute ssh <cluster-name>-m`

Comment: Thanks, i got the error - (gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) Error while connecting [4033: 'not authorized'].

Comment: Seems you are using IAP, you need to add `--tunnel-through-iap`, see https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#--tunnel-through-iap

Comment: After SSHing into the master node, you can use `systemctl status jupyter` to check the Jupyter service status.

Answer (score 0):

You can SSH into the master node with `gcloud compute ssh <cluster-name>-m`, then check the status of the following 3 services:

```
systemctl status jupyter
systemctl status knox
systemctl status google-dataproc-component-gateway
```

Restart them if needed:

```
sudo systemctl restart jupyter
sudo systemctl restart knox
sudo systemctl restart google-dataproc-component-gateway
```

Also, check the Knox log at `/var/log/knox/gateway.log`.